# Android studio App executing error

Tags: android, android-studio

I have installed Google Android studio latest version and created a sample application. I got the following error when executing the application.I have spend more than half day to resolve the problem but I could not get any solution.I have attached the error appeared in the console, please help me.

Error is:

```
:app:packageDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive overrides final method equals.(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

Edit:
I have done the following changes in the studio setting but it does not works.
Step 1: Go to the dependencies tab by clicking "open module setting -> and dependencies tab"

Step2 : I see two entries in the tab window (as shown in the following picture)
[image]

I removed the first entry,got the same error and I removed second entry got the app theme missing error.
please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 3):

the best solution is remove Bouncy Castel jar file in java folder on  $JAVA_HOME, directory 
involved through android studio like 
 `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext`

Answer (score 0):

i started having this error when i added Bouncy Castel as a Provider (see http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Provider+Installation).

So i just disable it from the `Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\lib\security\java.security` files and everything went back to normal.

```
#
# List of providers and their preference orders (see above):
#
security.provider.1=sun.security.provider.Sun
#security.provider.2=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
security.provider.3=sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign
security.provider.4=sun.security.ec.SunEC
```

Answer (score 0):

I also face this Problem， it's spend me many time。

There is only one solution to fix this problem：

Just delete bcprov-*.jar from your $JAVA_HOME, this is userful for me.

Answer (score -1):

I think that there are two different versions of same *jar* in your `classpath`. So this may be the cause that a effecting class is compiling from one and running from other. check your `build.gradle` and also try to rebuild your project.

Comment: How can I check same version of jar existing in the project structure? If exist two same version jar files what have to do?

Comment: As i have said check your build.gradle in your module there will be dependencies see if there is multiple jar has defined or not. and you can also check from going to 'open module setting' by right click on your module. then goto dependencies tab and check there.

If there is multiple entries try to remove the one which has lower version or if same version than remove any one.

Comment: I have checked the dependencies and there are two entries called "{dir=lib...." and "com.android.support:...", if I remove com.android.support or "{dir=libe.." entry got the App theme is not found exception while gradle sync , :app:packageDebug respectively. I have edited question with screen sort. please help me resolve the error.

Comment: you might be getting the app theme error because of the appcompact library. well i found it very annoying while creating the app in new version of android.

Well i know one solution of getting rid of this error that remove the appcompact library and than you might be getting the error in style.xml at Theme.appcompact.Light.

change Theme.appcompact.Light to @android:/style.Theme.Light in all style.xml file and the error will be gone.